# I am having trouble of reading environment variable from azure app service configuration for my REACT app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

I have added my variable in azure app service configuration and try to read it from my react application the following way, but no luck. Can anyone save the day?[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  console.log(process.env);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>{process.env.REACT_APP_TITLE}</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think you can raise a support ticket for help, because I can get service configuration  in express project.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 1):

This is my test code. I build project and deploy it in windows and linux.

I found it not works, it should be a bug. You can [raise a support ticket to confirm it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

[image]

Below is my test result.

[image]

**Related Posts:**

In express project, it works for me, I have tested it before.

[Retrieve Azure environment variables in NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805604/retrieve-azure-environment-variables-in-nodejs/63806093#63806093)