# Environment Variables are undefined in Azure Service App

Tags: node.js, azure, devops

I'm breaking my head over this - I've had the same environment working with the variables 100% (and also on the local env ofcourse)- but I've created another App Service on Azure with the same workflow and all of the env variables defined under the App Settings (Configurations tab) are undefined when running the job in workflow. I'm using the default YML file that Azure created when you deploy it using the Deployment Center. The start command is very simple:

```
"build": "node app.js",
```

And this is the YML file:

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - xxxxxxx

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'xxxxxxxxx'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_74C0CC726E3C4567B0FXXXXXXXXXXC }}
          package: .
```

No matter what I do, the process.env.X variables are all undefined, and if you list all variables using SSH on the same instance, I see the variables there, which drives me even more crazy!

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am unable to read environment variable from azure app service configuration from my REACT app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67576612/i-am-unable-to-read-environment-variable-from-azure-app-service-configuration-fr)

Comment: You can refer to [Retrieve Azure environment variables in NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805604/retrieve-azure-environment-variables-in-nodejs)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT none of these helped. I have deployed another environment that is exactly the same and it worked there. I was wondering if there are other settings other than the App Settings section in Azure that I should use. Btw, this is a nodejs server, not a browser. Any other idea?

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that this variable is being used while deploying (and not in runtime specifically?) - MONGO URI for DB connection

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Shinoy Babu ,We can try to add the environment variable in pipeline while deploying which will reflect in our App service in Azure after deploying.

[image]

Also if want to configure through Azure portal you can [**`refer this`**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/secret-variables-are-undefined-in-nodejs-functions/711273)

For more information please refer the below links:

- [***SO THREAD| How to use environment variables in React app hosted in Azure***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313330/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-react-app-hosted-in-azure)